# Rollover very slow

Tags: javascript, rollover, rollovers

I just published my new website but I have just a little problem to solve.
I'm absolutely self taught when it comes to web design.

As you can see here http://www.thisisfed.com the rollovers are really slow,
is there a way to solve this **anyhow?**

I used a simple toggle javascript

```
  [...] onmouseover="toggle_visibility('id');" onmouseout="hide('id');"
```

And this is how the javascript works

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) {

   var e = document.getElementById(id);

   if(e.style.visibility == 'hidden')
      e.style.visibility = 'visible';
   else
      e.style.visibility = 'hidden';

   }
```

Thanks for any help.

Fed.

Comment: there are many wrongs in your coding. You should try to avoind inline javascript (i.e. : `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes), there's no point defining a "toggle" function if you use another function to hide your content, and you may want to use the `display` property instead of the `visibility` one, among other remarks. Now for what I saw rollovers are working quick, but you should reproduce this in a jsFiddle anyway so that your question won't become obsolete as soon as it is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's not slow. The images are being shown the second time you rollover the titles, that's because when you rollover the first time there is no inline style and it's going to your "else" option of your "if" statement (where you hide the image).

As someone pointed out already, there are a lot of things to improve in your code but in the meantime, you could add a default inline style for your images, to be hidden, and then update your **toggle_visibility** and **hide** functions to be:

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) {    
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if (e.style.visibility == 'hidden') e.style.visibility = 'visible';
     else e.style.visibility = 'hidden';

 }

 function hide(id) {
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     if (e.style.visibility == 'visible') e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     else e.style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
```

[Fiddle demo here.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Z4av8/14/)

Comment: thank you for your quick reply!
I've tried what you wrote up here but it's still the same thing, the image is shown at the second rollover.